# PS3 | Updated to version 4.85 issue

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, monitor

My PS3 is Super Slim. So I just updated my PS3 to 4.85 which was working well before I updated it. I ticked the box "Turn off PS3 after software installation" and I let the PS3 update do its thing. After the update, it's not showing anything on the display anymore but the PS3's power light is lit green. I'm not sure if there's an issue on the update itself but upon checking on the 4.85, it just says "This system software update improves the quality of the system performance."

Things I did already:

- Hold the power button for video/display reset settings *(things i see on the internet for display settings issue)*. Didn't
  work as I cannot see anything in the first place.
- Tried my PS4's working HDMI and it's still not working. Tried my
  PS3's HDMI to my PS4 and it's working so it's not the cables.
- Unplug all the cables and power and let them rest for a couple of
  minutes. Didn't work.
- Put a disc and the CD drive seems working but still no display.
- Controller is connected as I can switch ON the PS3 using it and the light on the controller is at "1" player.

I'm not sure if my PS3 is bricked already. Anyone experienced this after an update?
Any suggestions aside from having it checked at a Sony Service Center or to any PS3 repair shop?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I experienced the same issue with my **PS3 Slim**. I also checked the option *Turn off PS3 after software installation* while performing the update to **firmware 4.85**. After dinner, I returned to find the PS3 on with no signal to the TV. While on, it was not accessing the hard drive so I waited, *c. three hours*, before forcing a shut down. One issue I have not mentioned is *turning off the PS3 requires a long press of the power button.* Normally a brief press worked before this updqte. Neither attempting the video/display reset at startup by holding the power button until *the second s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

So I brought my PS3 to a console repair shop and tested it and it seems that the chip for HDMI output got busted. He replaced it and it's working again.

Based on his experience, the problem is somewhat common and most PS3 owners that have the same problem is keeping their PS3 plugged on the power even though it's not in use. Only thing we can think of is static electricity.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can goto the recovery menu. Hold down the PS3 power button until you hear 2 consecutive beeps then let it go. Then goto system reformat and go through that process. If that doesn't work. Pop in another Hard drive and then boot up again and it will ask you to reinstall. If that doesn't work, you have a bricked system which does happen after a PS3 update. I've seen it happen at my repair shop many times and there's nothing you can do about it except getting another system. The culprit sometimes comes from the DVD drive or some other part of the system not working then a firmware updates and checks if these parts are working and if not, it will brick the system. It's a security measure by sony to make sure you aren't modding your system.

Comment: I think I saw this procedure already but since there's no display, I cannot navigate the PS3 blindly as there's no display. It's working now after the HMDI chip replacement. Thanks for answering.